# libGDX Character nullpointer

Tags: java, libgdx

I am a beginner in programming and I am working on making an RPG using libGDX. I have some stuff set up, and for some reason when I get to the screen which is supposed to show the main character, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FirstRPG.AbstractEntity.setLinearVelocity(AbstractEntity.java:220)
    at FirstRPG.screens.Player.handleEvents(Player.java:138)
    at FirstRPG.screens.Player.draw(Player.java:193)
    at FirstRPG.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:16)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at FirstRPG.screens.FirstRPG.render(FirstRPG.java:20)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:207)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

I have an Abstract Class set up to combine scence2d and box2d, the error is with the setLinearVelocity method:

```
public void setLinearVelocity(Vector2 v) {
        body.setLinearVelocity(v);
}
```

which is used in an event handler I have set up in the class for the Player:

```
public void handleEvents() {
    this.move = Movement.IDLE;
    if ((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) || (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W))) {
        setLinearVelocity(0.0f, 5.0f);
        this.setY(this.getPosition().y * PIXELS_PER_METER);
        this.dir = Direction.UP;
        this.move = Movement.WALKING;
    } else if ((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)) || (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S))) {
        setLinearVelocity(0.0f, -5.0f);
        this.setY(this.getPosition().y * PIXELS_PER_METER);
        this.dir = Direction.DOWN;
        this.move = Movement.WALKING;
    } else if ((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) || (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A))) {
        setLinearVelocity(-5.0f, 0.0f);
        this.setX(this.getPosition().x * PIXELS_PER_METER);
        this.dir = Direction.LEFT;
        this.move = Movement.WALKING;
    } else if ((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) || (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D))) {
        setLinearVelocity(5.0f, 0.0f);
        this.setX(this.getPosition().x * PIXELS_PER_METER);
        this.dir = Direction.RIGHT;
        this.move = Movement.WALKING;
    } else {
        setLinearVelocity(0.0f, 0.0f);
        this.setX(this.getPosition().x * PIXELS_PER_METER);
        this.setY(this.getPosition().y * PIXELS_PER_METER);
        this.move = Movement.IDLE;
    }
}
```

I have used this way of making a character before, and I do not understand why it is giving me a NullPointerException

Comment: `body` in your `FirstRPG.AbstractEntity` is `null`. That's obvious and you won't even need to debug in this case to find that. Please read a Java tutorial to understand what `NullpointerExceptions` are, because those are most of the time the easiest ones to fix. Since the code you showed us doesn't show the part where you initialize `body`, we cannot help you anymore at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(0.0f, 5.0f)`);

Otherwise from your code it just looks like you are passing it two floats instead of a vector.